# Possible to populate variable class from variable dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, model

I have the following function:

```
public static bool PopulateModelByDictionaryOne()
{
    var model = new ModelOne();

    foreach (var Item in Data.DictOne)
    {
        model.Dictionary.Add(Item.Key, Item.Value);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Dictionary is a public dictionary set by model.

I would like to make this class variable to allow custom model and custom Data.Dict. I have found the following (not tested yet):

```
var model = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(className));
```

Where className is a variable to pass to the function.

**Questions:**

1) How do I reference the model.Dictionary in this case (all model classes have a dictionary)

2) How do I make Data.DictOne variable?

Comment: Smells like you need a generic class but based on what you have shown here I would have to make a guess if it really solves your issue.

Comment: You should be able to deal with the issue by creating your own interface like _IModel_ which enforces the Dictionary as e.g. a property. In this way you should be able to pass/use any class which implements the interface you specified. After creating the instance with `Activator.CreateInstance` you can then access the instance as a reference of the interface like `IModel model = Activator.CreateInstance(...);`

But: I must admit that I am not sure if I really understood the question correctly...

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you mean that you want to use this method `PopulateModelByDictionaryOne` in any type of `Model`? not just `ModelOne` and they all have to contain `Dictionary`? and you want to populate this dictionary from some kind of DataSource like `Data.DictOne`

Comment: I would like to  have a generic function (but based on the comments so far might be better to take this to a base model and let current models extend that one). But the function needs to take the model name and the data source name as variables (one question) and how do I reference the different models dictionaries (question two / all dictionaries have the same name, but as currently 'model.Dictionary' does not compile)

Comment: I see, your function cannot have a parameter for the actual `DataSource`, it have to take the model name `type name` and the DataSource name `DataSource type name` as parameters? right? Although you can easily create a generic method, and then create a generic interface for the model for this regard. If you can provide the actual parameters, not the types name, I really suggest you avoid working with reflection.

Comment: Ok I'll dig a bit deeper to see if I can change things around a bit and find a few generic interfaces for the model around here

Comment: I can give you an answer on how to make this method generic, but I don't know if this will solve you problem, because I still don't understand why  do you want to pass the type name of the data source and the type name of the model

Comment: If you would like to give a start I can learn further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the following:

1. You have some kind of `DataSource` this data source has a
   `Dictionary` with certain data types for `Key` and `Value`
2. You have a method called `PopulateModelByDictionaryOne` this method takes
   a `DataSource` as `Parameter` and create new instance of a certain
   model and then populate a property of type `Dictionary` whose `Key`
   and `Value` types match the ones on the `DataSource` type.

If my assumptions are correct. You can create a generic interface type for your models `IDicationaryDataModel<TKey,TValue>` this interface contains single property of type `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` therefore you enforce the existence of this property on any model implements this interface.

```
public interface IDicationaryDataModel<TKey, TValue>
{
    IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

And then you create another generic interface type `IDataSource<TKey,TValue>` this interface will enforce the existence of a property of type `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` on your data source.

```
public interface IDataSource<TKey,TValue>
{
    IDictionary<TKey,TValue> DictOne { get; set; }
}
```

So, your model will implement the interface like this:

```
public class ModelOne : IDicationaryDataModel<string, string>
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

And your data source will implement the interface like this:

```
public class DataSource : IDataSource<string, string>
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> DictOne { get; set; }
}
```

Therefore, your method will be:

```
    public static bool PopulateModelByDictionaryOne<TModel,TDataSource,TKey,TValue>(TDataSource dataSource)
            where TModel:IDicationaryDataModel<TKey,TValue>,new()
        where TDataSource:IDataSource<TKey,TValue>
    {
        var model = new TModel();
        foreach (var Item in dataSource.DictOne)
        {
            model.Dictionary.Add(Item.Key, Item.Value);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This way, you are free to chose the pair DataSource / Model as you like. Your method is as generic as it could be :). Also, you can pass the instance of the model instead of instantiating it inside this method this way you can get rid of the `new()` constraint. By using the method, you don't need to use `Reflection`.